# It is possible make infinite scroll using the RecyclerView Firebase UI?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using the RecyclerView firebase UI and found nothing realacionando the implementation of the infinite scroll. Today I'm looking for all the data from one node when loading the activity equal to firebase the code example, would leave more optimized this part request, seeking little data to be displayed and go loaded as user navigation.

Comment: Infinite scroll is an [outstanding feature request for FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/17). If you'd like to weigh in on that feature request, Github is the best place to do so. If you're trying to implement infinite scroll yourself, show the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a workaround by adding a counter for each row in the database and to get them by

`orderByChild("counter").startAt(10*n).endAt(10*(n+1));`

n: 0 - item_count/10-1

I didnt try it but i believe it can be managed with database parameters.